# Zend Framework : What is difference between partial and render view? How to use global variable in partial?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube

Basically, I know difference bween Partial and Render View but I need more details and how can I solve below problem.

In view.phtml template, I have written below code.

```
foreach($this->pageUserActivity as $pageUserActivityItem) {   

switch ($pageUserActivityItem->activityType) { 
                   case 'likecommentcast':
                     echo $this->partial('activity/_likecommentcast.phtml', array('activityItem'=>$pageUserActivityItem,'loggedInUser'=>$this->loggedInUserStd, 'pageType' => $this->pageType));
                     break;
                   case 'cast':
                        echo $this->partial('activity/_cast.phtml', array('activityItem'=>$pageUserActivityItem,'loggedInUser'=>$this->loggedInUserStd, 'pageType' => $this->pageType));
                     break;
                   case 'castcomment':
                         echo $this->partial('activity/_castcomment.phtml', array('activityItem'=>$pageUserActivityItem,'loggedInUser'=>$this->loggedInUserStd, 'pageType' => $this->pageType));
                     break;
    }
}
```

Now, if activity has youtube link then I need to fetch data using Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient & Zend_Gdata_YouTube and embed data as below.

```
$email = Zend_Registry::get('config')->google->email;
$passwd = Zend_Registry::get('config')->google->password;

try {
   $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, Zend_Gdata_YouTube::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
   echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}

$youtube = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($client,'{API_KEY}');
```

I have above code in all three files (activity/_cast.phtml, activity/_likecommentcast.phtml, activity/_castcomment.phtml) but this makes script slow as I am calling login api all time. I want such that any of activity already has youtube link and we already initiated $client and $youtube then use it again if further feed has youtube link instead of initiating $client and $youtube again and again.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the view? STAHP!

Comment: I am displaying activity feed like FaceBook so this view keeps on repeat so I used partial view helper to display each activity.